# convert 2 column long format table to wide format

Tags: r

I have a table like this:

```
col_1  col_2
1      a
1      b
1      c
2      a
2      b
```

and would like to convert to this:

```
col_1  col_2
1      a,b,c
2      a,b
```

What's the simplest way of doing this? I've tried playing around with tidyverse package but can't get my head around it.

Thanks

Comment: Try `aggregate(col_2 ~ col_1, df1, toString)` or `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(col_1) %>% summarise(col_2 = paste(col_2, collapse=","))`

Comment: I wonder how many duplicates of this question are in SO?